# Backbone trigger custom event after conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to create a custom event but only if two conditions are verified, in my code below I need trigger an event only if two add on collection are completed. Most specificly I need trigger an event only when addInstagram and addTweets functions are completed.

```
var Integrated = Backbone.Collection.extend({




model:IntegratedModel,
nextUrlInstagram:undefined,
InstagramQuery:undefined,
twitterQuery:undefined,
page: 0,


comparator:"dateString",

initialize: function () {

this.TweetsCollection = new Tweets();
this.InstagramCollection = new Instagrams();
this.listenTo(this.TweetsCollection,'reset',this.addTweets);
this.listenTo(this.InstagramCollection,'reset',this.addInstagram);
},






fetch: function() {
this.reset();
var self=this;
this.TweetsCollection.query=this.twitterQuery;
this.TweetsCollection.page=this.page;
this.TweetsCollection.fetch();






this.InstagramCollection.userId=this.InstagramQuery;
this.InstagramCollection.fetch();   


 },



addTweets: function(){//when this function and function below are completeed trigger event

console.log(this.TweetsCollection);
this.add(this.TweetsCollection.toJSON());

  },


addInstagram: function(){

console.log(this.InstagramCollection);
this.add(this.InstagramCollection.toJSON());

},









    });




   return Integrated;



  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, I've created a method called `when`.

So, you can put at the end of your `fetch` method:

```
 this.when([this.TweetsCollection, this.InstagramCollection], 'sync', this.onBothLoaded);
```

And your `when` would be something like this:

```
 when: function (models, eventName, callback) {

     callback = _.after(models.length, callback);

     for (var i = 0, l = models.length; i < l; i++)
        this.listenToOnce(models[i], eventName, callback);

 }
```

This should work.

Hope I've helped.